# Symfony: How encode / in URL parameter?

Tags: symfony

I want to build RESTful API with URLs something like:

First route: `http://example.com/api/{element_name}/aaa/{related_name}` and
Second route: `http://example.com/api/{element_name}/bbb/{related_name}`.

Everything is simple and easy when `element_name` is integer or simple text.
Things get complicated when parameter `{element_name}` has "/" char in the name, because even if I encode `/` by `%2f` (url encode) routing will decode `%2f` before process routes.

For example when I want to generate URL to first route and I have `{element_name} = xyz` and `{related_name} = ooo` then the URL will be `http://example.com/api/xyz/aaa/ooo` and it's OK.

But when I have `{element_name} = xyz/bbb` and `{related_name} = ooo` then the URL should be: `http://example.com/api/xyz%2fbbb/aaa/ooo` but routing first will decode url and make: `http://example.com/api/xyz/bbb/aaa/ooo` and it isn't OK because doesn't match to first route.

How I should do that?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add requirement while configuring the routes in your controller. Like so :

```
class DefaultController
{
  /**
  * @Route("/share/{token}", name="share", requirements={"token"=".+"})
  */
  public function share($token)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

it's explained in the SF doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: It isn't valid solution because url like:

http://example.com/api/xyz%2fbbb/aaa/ooo

should lead to **first route** with parameters **{element_name} = xyz/bbb** and **{related_name} = ooo**

but routing will resolve it as

http://example.com/api/xyz/bbb/aaa/ooo

and it will be matched with first route with parameters {element_name} = xyz and {related_name} = aaa/ooo when you use .+ requirement for {element_name}

or it will be matched with second route with parameters {element_name} = xyz/bbb and {related_name} = ooo when you use .+ requirement for {related_name}